# Can anyone recommend a good diacritic keyboard for rendering Pali, Sanskrit, etc?

Tags: pali-language, pali

This isn't particularly about Buddhism, but I'm wondering what people are using for unicode characters.

Comment: Maybe move this to meta?  It does pertain to Buddhist languages.

Comment: I don't know... Doesn't belong on the meta either. If anyone has an answer they can reply here in the comments I guess. The rules are just rules but there is a reason we have to keep enforcing them...

Comment: No worries.  Other than a little comp sci dabbling, I have the technical skills of a slightly sophisticated caveman.  ;-) I just wasn't sure where else to look than here.

Comment: I don't know if this will be useful for you but when I need to write Pali letters, I find them on google and copy/paste them into Buddhism SE. Of course this might not be helpful if wanting to literally write the language. For small sentences, words and letters the copy/paste-method can work.

Comment: Found one - http://fsnow.com/pali/keyboard/ .  I can write Pāli now!  It's certainly a more effective solution than hammering on my keyboard with a large brontosaurus bone!

Comment: Pali is usually rendered in Roman/ Latin characters with diacritical marks - the same ones used by Sanskrit. Pali doesn't have its own script. However, I think it's possible to render Pali also in the Sinhala script and the Devanagari script (used by Sanskrit). Hence, you can also use keyboards that render Roman/ Latin characters with Sanskrit diacritical marks, Sinhala script and Devanagari script.